# How to import variables from one data frame to another in R given both have no attribute in common and have differential number of rows?

Tags: r

I need a help. I have, a dataframe , say, `df1` having variables

```
x1,x2,x3,x4,x5
```

Now I have another dataframe , say, `df2`, having variables

```
x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,...,x20
```

Now I want to include or append

```
x6,x7,x8,x11,x20
```

from `df2` to `df1`. Mind it we do not have any attribute in `df1` and `df2` common that is

```
dfi != dfj  for i != j
```

`df1` and `df2` do not have the same number of rows nor do they have any attribute in common. I know it can be done using a loop but both my datasets are over a million observations. Also `merge()` and `append()` does not work here because there are no attributes in common.

```
str(df2)


'data.frame':   173259 obs. of  308 variables:
 $ Month.Date                                          : Factor w/ 14 levels "1/1/2018","10/1/2017",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ Total.Subscriber.Line.International.Cost            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Total.Subscriber.Line.LD.Cost                       : num  0.09 0.05 0 0 0 0 0.33 0 0.05 0 ...
 $ Total.Subscriber.Line.Monthly.Margin                : num  -1.1 -1.06 -1 0 -1 -1 -0.36 -1 -1.05 0 ...
 $ Total.Subscriber.Line.Monthly.Revenue               : num  -1 -1 -1 0 -1 -1 0 -1 -1 0 ...
 $ Total.Subscriber.Line.Rate.Plan.MRC.Revenue         : int  -1 -1 -1 0 -1 -1 0 -1 -1 0 ...
 $ Total.Subscriber.Line.Roaming.Revenue               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Total.Subscriber.Line.Total.Monthly.Cost            : num  0.1 0.06 0 0 0 0 0.36 0 0.05 0 ...
 $ Total.Subscriber.Line.Interconnect.Cost             : num  0.01 0.01 0 0 0 0 0.02 0 0 0 ...
 $ Total.Subscriber.Line.Domestic.Voice.Roaming.Revenue: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Total.Subscriber.Line.Domestic.Voice.Roaming.Cost   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Total.Subscriber.Line.Domestic.Data.Roaming.Cost    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Total.Subscriber.Line.Device.Cost                   : num  190 1 1 1 1.01 1 190 190 1 190 ...
 $ Total.Subscriber.Line.Data.Roaming.Revenue          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Total.Status.Changes.In.Month                       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Total.Data.Roaming.2G.Cost                          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Total.Data.Roaming.3G.Cost                          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Total.Data.Roaming.4G.Cost                          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Total.Data.Roaming.Wifi.Cost                        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Total.Device.Changes.In.Month                       : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 ...
 $ Total.Price.Plan.Changes.In.Month                   : int  0 0 1 1 0 2 1 0 0 1 ...
 $ Total.Records                                       : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Zip.Plus.4.Code                                     : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ WIFI.Flag                                           : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Wednesday.Store.Hours                               : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Voice.Data.Description                              : Factor w/ 4 levels "1xVoice Only",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Voice.Data.Code                                     : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Vendor.Id                                           : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Update.Process.Code                                 : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Tuesday.Store.Hours                                 : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Thursday.Store.Hours                                : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Text.Messaging.Flag                                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Tertiary.Roaming.SID                                : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Tertiary.Roaming.SID.Carrier                        : Factor w/ 18 levels "","BLUEGRASS CELLULAR, INC.",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Tertiary.Roaming.SID.Location.Percent               : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Tertiary.Roaming.SID.Name                           : Factor w/ 248 levels "","ABBEVILLE",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Tertiary.Roaming.SID.State                          : Factor w/ 50 levels "","AL","AR","AZ",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Tertiary.Roaming.SID.State.Name                     : Factor w/ 13 levels "","CAN","DEU",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Tertiary.Onnet.Location.Percent                     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Tertiary.Onnet.Longitude                            : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Tertiary.Onnet.Site.Name                            : Factor w/ 12084 levels "","AATPMIBE",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Tertiary.Onnet.State                                : Factor w/ 52 levels "","AK","AL","AR",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Tertiary.Onnet.Switch.Id                            : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Tertiary.Onnet.Zip                                  : Factor w/ 6798 levels "","1001","100100000",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Tertiary.Onnet.Latitude                             : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Tertiary.Onnet.City                                 : Factor w/ 3830 levels "","ABERDEEN",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Tertiary.Onnet.Cell.Id                              : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Territory.Description                               : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Technology.Description                              : Factor w/ 7 levels "2G","3G","EVDO REV0",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ Technology.Code                                     : int  13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 ...
 $ Sunday.Store.Hours                                  : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Sub.Valuation.Cluster                               : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Subscriber.Number                                   : num  1.31e+07 5.34e+07 1.49e+08 2.23e+08 3.28e+08 ...
 $ Subscriber.Count                                    : int  492 496 527 491 501 479 486 608 496 481 ...
 $ Subscriber.Attribute.Device.SKU.Number              : Factor w/ 703 levels "AL2017BASB","AL2017BKBL",..: 194 193 193 195 56 193 194 194 193 194 ...
 $ Subscriber.Attribute.Business                       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Subscriber.Activity.Customer.System.Code            : Factor w/ 1 level "EW": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Store.Type                                          : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Sub.Market.Code                                     : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Sub.MRC.Cluster                                     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Subscriber.Activity.BAN.Address.City                : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Subscriber.Activity.BAN.Address.Zip                 : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Subscriber.Activity.Business                        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Store.Status                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Store.Primary.Contact.Phone.Number                  : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Store.Primary.Contact.Name                          : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Store.Owner                                         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Store.Open.Date                                     : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Store.Number                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Store.Close.Date                                    : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Store.Format                                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Store.Location.Code                                 : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Store.Location.Name                                 : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Store.Manager                                       : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Store.Manager.Private.Phone.Number                  : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Store.Name                                          : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Sprint.Store.Zip.Code                               : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Sprint.TV.Capable.Flag                              : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Square.Footage.Quantity                             : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Standard.Monthly.Recurring.Charge.Amount            : Factor w/ 2 levels "$0.00 ","($1.00)": 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ Status.Name                                         : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Sprint.Store.State.Code                             : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Sprint.Store.Longitude.Number                       : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Sprint.Store.Latitude.Number                        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Sprint.Store.City.Name                              : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Sprint.Store.Address.Line.1.Text                    : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Source.Sequence.Number                              : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Segment                                             : int  53 53 53 53 53 53 53 53 53 53 ...
 $ Secondary.Roaming.SID.State.Name                    : Factor w/ 16 levels "","BRB","CAN",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Secondary.Roaming.SID.State                         : Factor w/ 53 levels "","AL","AR","AZ",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Secondary.Roaming.SID.Name                          : Factor w/ 447 levels "","ABERDEEN",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Secondary.Roaming.SID.Location.Percent              : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Secondary.Roaming.SID.Carrier                       : Factor w/ 25 levels "","APPALACHIAN WIRELESS",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Secondary.Roaming.SID                               : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Secondary.Onnet.Zip                                 : Factor w/ 5717 levels "","10003","1001",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Secondary.Onnet.Switch.Id                           : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Secondary.Onnet.State                               : Factor w/ 48 levels "","AL","AR","AZ",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Secondary.Onnet.Site.Name                           : Factor w/ 9641 levels "","ABDLFLAT",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Secondary.Onnet.Cell.Id                             : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

I have the following for df1:

```
 'data.frame':  387850 obs. of  106 variables:
 $ X.NAME.                                : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X..Calls.Completed                     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Account.Attribute.BAN.Address.State    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Account.Code.Sub.Type                  : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
 $ Account.Code.Type                      : Factor w/ 1 level "R": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Account.End.Date                       : Factor w/ 1 level "12/31/2999": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Account.Start.Date                     : Factor w/ 73 levels "1/11/2018","1/2/2017",..: 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 ...
 $ Account.Tenure.Days                    : int  361078 361078 361078 361078 361078 361078 361078 361078 361078 361078 ...
 $ Account.Tenure.Months                  : int  11863 11863 11863 11863 11863 11863 11863 11863 11863 11863 ...
 $ Account.Tenure.Years                   : int  989 989 989 989 989 989 989 989 989 989 ...
 $ Answered                               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Brand.Name                             : Factor w/ 9 levels "Apple","Assurance",..: 1 1 1 1 6 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ Business                               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Busy                                   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ BYOD.Indicator                         : Factor w/ 3 levels "","N","Y": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Call.Attempts                          : int  1 1 1 4 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Call.Forwarded.Calls                   : int  3 16 0 2 1 1 3 3 12 12 ...
 $ Churn.Flag                             : Factor w/ 3 levels "","N","Y": 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Consecutive.Calls                      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Count.Subscriber.Activation            : int  25 1 1 1 32 25 1 1 27 27 ...
 $ Count.Subscriber.Deactivation          : int  33 19 24 24 33 33 19 19 21 21 ...
 $ Credit.Class.Category                  : Factor w/ 1 level "SUB-PRIME": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Device                                 : Factor w/ 18 levels "","Alcatel","Apple",..: 3 3 3 3 14 9 7 10 14 14 ...
 $ Device.Color.Name                      : Factor w/ 23 levels "Berry","Black",..: 17 7 17 2 22 2 15 3 2 17 ...
 $ Device.Description                     : Factor w/ 1693 levels "ALCATEL 2017B FLIP",..: 807 780 894 569 1240 1014 536 1042 442 1462 ...
 $ Device.Model.Type.Name                 : Factor w/ 620 levels "Assurance Kyocera Forte",..: 243 245 251 225 417 281 208 320 441 466 ...
 $ Device.Type.Name                       : Factor w/ 4 levels "Handset","N/A",..: 3 3 3 3 1 1 3 1 3 3 ...
 $ Handset.Change.Flag                    : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Last.Device.Change.Date                : Factor w/ 1658 levels "","1/1/2015",..: 1 1 85 1 1 1 1 1 194 1 ...
 $ Last.Price.Plan.Change.Date            : Factor w/ 1203 levels "","1/1/2015",..: 1 1 62 1 234 1 632 820 249 1127 ...
 $ Liability.Code                         : Factor w/ 1 level "CL": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Line.End.Date                          : Factor w/ 567 levels "1/1/2018","1/10/2016",..: 145 145 292 145 145 156 145 145 145 145 ...
 $ Line.Start.Date                        : Factor w/ 2318 levels "1/1/2016","1/1/2017",..: 154 873 1218 913 193 799 906 1525 636 1645 ...
 $ Line.Tenure.In.Days                    : int  1 37 14 61 2183 0 32 2156 1533 1346 ...
 $ Line.Tenure.In.Months                  : int  0 1 0 2 72 0 1 71 50 44 ...
 $ Line.Tenure.In.Years                   : int  0 0 0 0 5 0 0 5 4 3 ...
 $ Manufacturer.Name                      : Factor w/ 17 levels "Alcatel","Apple",..: 2 2 2 2 13 8 6 9 13 13 ...
 $ Market.Name                            : Factor w/ 98 levels "Alabama","Albuquerque",..: 37 31 20 63 6 56 6 66 72 94 ...
 $ Mobile.Orig.Calls                      : int  1 1 1 4 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Mobile.Orig.Consecutive.Calls          : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Mobile.Orig.MOU                        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Mobile.Orig.Sequential.Calls           : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Mobile.Term.Calls                      : int  3 3 1 0 0 1 0 3 0 1 ...
 $ Mobile.Term.Consecutive.Calls          : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Mobile.Term.MOU                        : num  3.82 3.35 0 0 0 1.22 0 0.33 0 0.17 ...
 $ Mobile.Term.Sequential.Calls           : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Month.Date                             : Factor w/ 14 levels "1/1/2018","10/1/2017",..: 1 7 9 9 4 1 7 7 5 5 ...
 $ Months.on.Device                       : int  0 1 3 2 72 0 1 71 16 44 ...
 $ Months.on.Price.Plan                   : int  0 1 3 2 14 0 1 35 16 5 ...
 $ Month.Year                             : int  2018 2018 2018 2018 2017 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 ...
 $ MSRP.Amount                            : num  600 550 450 450 145 ...
 $ Owner.Owner.Description                : Factor w/ 1 level "ACN_INC": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Ported.in.Carrier                      : Factor w/ 2 levels "","SPRINT SPECTRUM LP": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Ported.out.Carrier                     : Factor w/ 12 levels "","BANDWIDTH.COM CLEC",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Prepaid.Postpaid.Subscriber            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Prepaid.Vs.Poastpaid                   : Factor w/ 1 level "POSTPAID": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Price.Plan.Change.Flag                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ Primary.Onnet.Cell.Id                  : int  0 0 0 66 19 0 0 4008 0 0 ...
 $ Primary.Onnet.City                     : Factor w/ 3697 levels "","ABBOTT","ABERDEEN",..: 1 1 1 2000 142 1 1 3574 1 1 ...
 $ Primary.Onnet.Latitude                 : num  0 0 0 33.4 39.2 ...
 $ Primary.Onnet.Location.Percent         : num  50 20.9 0 0 0 ...
 $ Primary.Onnet.Longitude                : num  0 0 0 -111.9 -76.6 ...
 $ Primary.Onnet.Site.Name                : Factor w/ 10912 levels "","AATSMIAB",..: 1 1 1 5462 691 1 1 476 1 1 ...
 $ Primary.Onnet.State                    : Factor w/ 49 levels "","AL","AR","AZ",..: 1 1 1 4 20 1 1 34 1 1 ...
 $ Primary.Onnet.Switch.Id                : int  40 423 75 183 161 29 161 426 43 203 ...
 $ Primary.Onnet.Zip                      : Factor w/ 6386 levels "","10003","1001",..: 1 1 1 5087 780 1 1 2479 1 1 ...
 $ Primary.Roaming.Location.Percent       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Primary.Roaming.SID                    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Primary.Roaming.SID.Carrier            : Factor w/ 29 levels "","ALASKA WIRELESS NETWORK - ACDMA",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Primary.Roaming.SID.Name               : Factor w/ 724 levels "","ABBEVILLE",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Primary.Roaming.SID.State              : Factor w/ 57 levels "","AK","AL","AR",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Primary.Roaming.SID.State.Name         : Factor w/ 24 levels "","AUS","AUT",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Ring.No.Answer                         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Roaming.Data.Limit                     : Factor w/ 2 levels "100MB","300MB": 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Roaming.Data.Limit.Exceeded.Code       : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Roaming.Voice.Limit                    : Factor w/ 1 level "800MOU": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Roaming.Voice.Limit.Exceeded.Code      : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Sequential.Calls                       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Status.Code                            : Factor w/ 4 levels "A","C","F","S": 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Status.Code.by.MDN                     : Factor w/ 4 levels "A","C","F","S": 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Status.Same.All.Month.By.Account.Number: Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Subscriber.Activity.BAN.Address.State  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Subscriber.Activity.Contract.Status    : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Subscriber.Activity.Price.Plan.Code    : Factor w/ 19 levels "ACNPLAN1","ACNPLAN10",..: 16 14 14 13 19 13 14 19 6 3 ...
 $ Subscriber.Attribute.Contract.Status   : Factor w/ 1 level "Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Subscriber.Attribute.Owner.Description : Factor w/ 1 level "ACN_INC": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Subscriber.Attribute.Price.Plan.Code   : Factor w/ 19 levels "ACNPLAN1","ACNPLAN10",..: 16 14 14 13 19 13 14 19 6 3 ...
 $ Subscriber.Line.Id                     : num  3.68e+09 3.76e+09 2.70e+09 3.73e+09 1.91e+08 ...
 $ Subscriber.Line.Status.Changed         : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Subscriber.Type                        : Factor w/ 1 level "MVNO": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Total.Calls                            : int  4 4 2 4 2 2 1 4 1 2 ...
 $ Total.MOU                              : num  3.82 3.35 0 0 0 1.22 0 0.33 0 0.17 ...
 $ Unassigned                             : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Total.Active.Accounts                  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Total.Active.Subscribers               : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Total.Data.Roaming.2G.MB               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Total.Data.Roaming.3G.MB               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Total.Data.Roaming.4G.MB               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Total.Data.Roaming.MB                  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Now I want to retain all the variables of df1 and add

```
Wifi.flag ,  Standard.Monthly.Recurring.Charge.Amount, 
Sprint.TV.Capable.Flag , Total.Price.Changes.In.Month , 
Total.Device.Changes.In.Month , 
Total.Subscriber.Line.Device.Cost,  Text.Messaging.Flag,Subscriber.Count(?=> 
How is it different from Total.Subscriber.Activation- 
Total.Subscriber.Deactivation?),   Sprint.TV.Capable.Flag,  Revenue.Non- 
Revenue,  Ready.Now.Code,  Quality.Description,  Push.Talk.Flag,  
NFC.Indicator,  Multimedia.Flag,  MP3.Flag  ,  Hot-Spot.Capable.Description  
,  GSM.Capable  ,  GPS.Flag  ,  Device.Rugged.Flag  ,  
Device.Operating.System.Name  ,Device.Cost.Amount, Device.Network.Flag,  
Device.System.Status.Code ,  Credit.Class.System.Status.Code  ,  
Credit.Class.Network.Flag  ,  CPO.Indicator  ,  Churn.Risk.Cluster  ,
Channel.Hierarchy.System.Status.Code  ,  Carrier.Aggregation,Camera.Flag,
Business.Geography.System.Status.Code  ,  Affiliate.Subscription.Flag  ,  
Account.Spending.Limit.Code
```

variables of df2 to df1 keeping all attributes of df1 intact.

Comment: Have df1 and df2 the same number of row and each row of the df1 is the same in df2 (for example the same individual that have the some variable in df1 and some variable in df2 and it is alway in the same place, like the first is in the first row in df1 and in df2)? If so, you only need `cbind`.

Comment: No this is not the case df1 and df2 do not have the same number of rows and neither they have any attribute in common so cbind probably does not work. And yes you people give a negative vote without thinking whether a user actually needs the answer or not. If the user is deprived of asking questions, you can imagine how much critical the issue will be especially if one is in R&D like me. You may consider my opinion as a rant but I am sorry.

Comment: Perhaps, the downvote is because there is no [mcve]? (I have not downvoted). And if *you* need an answer, please, consider what information the volunteers on SO would need to understand the question.

Comment: First of all, generally the downvotes arrive when you have not formatted well your question, or it seems not a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so, nothing personal, it's nice to take time to create a good question in a generous community like SO where people help free. Back in track, how do you imagine to join the two df if they have nothing in common? To help you to help us to help you (idem as @Uwe I've not downvoted, but you cannot reprove who did it).

Comment: Is there any requirement of the order in which the dataframes are combined? If not, you could a rowid variable to each dataframe, do a join using rowid as the key and then delete rowid from the merged dataframe.

Comment: I cannot post my dataset, not even a sample of it as the dimensions are huge(317,000*308). What I can do I can post an example and try to explain. I will do that but I think the question is very well interpretable. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @s_t then you are suggesting I create seperate variables in a temporary dataframe which includes all variables of df1 and then populate those attributes from df2 using a simple for.. loop, the way I thought on the contrary?

Comment: Sorry the question is not interpretable; none of us can understand what your criteria are for joining (no shared column, different number of rows... unless the row-indices have something in common?); people really are genuinely trying to help you. Please post `head(dput(df[..., 1:10], 10))` on both dataframes, at least for the first 10 rows and columns. Btw I did not downvote either.

Comment: Ok I will do that.

Comment: Is there any rule that tells which rows belong together? If it's not a common attribute nor the row number, how it is decided which row from `df1` belongs to which row of `df2`? What would a human being do to solve the problem?

Comment: How are the two dataframes thematically related and where did they come from? sales data? genomics? etc. Do they have anything vaguely incommon like an ID column, date/datestamp, username etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two datasets have nothing in common, it is questionable to combine them in my opinion, but for sure you have your reason.

One option would be to use bind_rows from `dplyr`, this would preserve the fact, that there's not connection between the rows:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(sample_df1, sample_df2[, c("x4", "x7")])

#    x1 x2   x3 x4   x7
#  1  1  6    a NA <NA>
#  2  2  7    b NA <NA>
#  3  3  8    c NA <NA>
#  4 NA NA <NA> 11    K
#  5 NA NA <NA> 12    L
#  6 NA NA <NA> 13    M
#  7 NA NA <NA> 14    N
#  8 NA NA <NA> 15    O
```

Another option would be to first combine the same number of rows and then add the remaining ones from the larger dataframe:

```
bind_cols(sample_df1, sample_df2[1:length(sample_df1), ]) %>% 
  bind_rows(sample_df2[-c(1:length(sample_df1)), ])

#   x1 x2   x3 x4 x7
# 1  1  6    a 11  K
# 2  2  7    b 12  L
# 3  3  8    c 13  M
# 4 NA NA <NA> 14  N
# 5 NA NA <NA> 15  O
```

But this way depends on the ordering of the data.

**Data**

```
sample_df1 <- 
  data.frame(x1 = 1:3, 
             x2 = 6:8, 
             x3 = letters[1:3], 
             stringsAsFactors = F)


sample_df2 <- 
  data.frame(x4 = 11:15, 
             x5 = 16:20, 
             x6 = letters[11:15], 
             x7 = LETTERS[11:15],
             stringsAsFactors = F)
```